# Why is the Ajax call not being hit?

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to apply a filter to data that is being displayed on a map but for some reason, the Ajax call that I have set up is not being executed. I can reach the console.log line in the view but anything after that in the Ajax call is never executed. This is being done in ASP.NET MVC.

I have similar Ajax calls in this project from other developers that function in a similar manner. I have tried to restructure my code to work in a similar manner, but with no success. The other developers have no idea what is going on either.

C# in the controller

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult MapFilter(string filterLake, bool filterPets)
{
    var filteredProperties = db.Properties.Include(a => a.PropertyCategory).Where(b => b.Status == true).Select(x => new { x.PropertyName, x.PropertyId, x.RatePerNight, x.RatePerWeek, x.MarketingTitle, x.Latitude, x.Longitude, x.Pets, x.PropertyCategory.PropertyCategoryName });

    if (filterLake != "")
        filteredProperties = filteredProperties.Where(a => a.PropertyCategoryName == filterLake);
    if (filterPets != true)
        filteredProperties = filteredProperties.Where(a => a.Pets == filterPets);

    var jsonProperties = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(filteredProperties);

    return new JsonResult()
    {
        Data = jsonProperties,
        JsonRequestBehavior = JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet
    };
}
```

JavaScript & Ajax in the View

```
var filterLake, filterPets;
var btnApplyFilters = document.getElementById("applyFilters");
var filterLakeNode = document.getElementById("filterLake");
var filterPetsNode = document.getElementById("filterPets");

$(document).ready(function () {
    btnApplyFilters.onclick = function () {
        filterLake = filterLakeNode.options[filterLakeNode.selectedIndex].value;
        filterPets = filterPetsNode.options[filterPetsNode.selectedIndex].value;
        console.log("Lake:|" + filterLake + "| Pets:|" + filterPets + "|");
        $.ajax({
            url: "/Estates/MapFilter",
            type: "Post",
            data: {
                "filterLake": filterLake,
                "filterPets": filterPets
            },
            success: function (result) {
                filteredMapData = result;
                console.log("Result = " + result);
                loadMapMarkers(true)
            }
        });
    };
})
```

When I run the program on localhost, I am able to reach the

```
console.log("Lake:|" + filterLake + "| Pets:|" + filterPets + "|");
```

line with no issues. Anything after does not run.

Comment: Just like success: there is an error: too. Use it to see what really the error is. You are not handling the errors, and the call isn't successful. https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Comment: I added the error to the Ajax call and realized from reading the error I was sending 0 & 1 not true & false. Thank you for the help!

Comment: You should check the network tab in your web developer tools (e.g. Chrome). This could a problem in many directions, e.g. wrong url, wrong routes, etc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need check `filterPets` value, it must be `true/false` then model binder can map with bool type.

With primitive type (`bool, int, float`) you should use `nullable` type `bool?` for preventing case the value incorrect format.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult MapFilter(string filterLake, bool? filterPets)
{
}
```

With this paramter if `filterPets` has wrong value, it will be null.